# bind vectors in a loop using R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, cbind

I need to add vectors[attributes] returned by `remove_outliers` function in a dataframe. Right now, I am getting a large matrix. I have tried append method(as following)

```
# function to calculate IQR and upper and lower limit of given attribute
remove_outliers <- function(attribute, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  IQR_val <- quantile(attribute, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  LF <- 1.5 * IQR(attribute, na.rm = na.rm)
  attribute_W_NA <- attribute
  attribute_W_NA[attribute < (IQR_val[1] - LF)] <- NA
  attribute_W_NA[attribute > (IQR_val[2] + LF)] <- NA
  attribute_W_NA
}

cleaned_data <- NULL

for(i in 1:ncol(data_rm_val)){
  # cleaned data with NA entries replacing outliers

    cleaned_data <- cbind(cleaned_data, remove_outliers(data_rm_val[,i]))

}
```

it results in large matrix

This is input dataframe:
[image]

current output is: (with cbind in loop)
[image]

and desired result should be a dataframe with the same number of rows and columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
PS: I am a newbie in R and Data Science.

Comment: For a loop try `cbind` rather than `append`, though `apply(data_rm_val, 2, remove_outliers)` will probably be faster and better for what you want.

Comment: If you're going to use a loop, preallocate an object of the proper size or you'll get horrible performance. That said, there are better ways to do this without a loop. If you add some data to your question, somebody will probably post one.

Comment: okay. I will try that. 
I tried cbind as well. I got a dataframe(a large matrix).

Comment: Isn't data frame your desired result? You call it after loop. Please show current and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `lapply` with your user defined function avoiding the need of cbinding or appending. When using `lapply()` on a dataframe you run operations on each column:

```
cleaned_data <- data.frame(lapply(data_rm_val, remove_outliers))
```

Now above assumes your defined function, *remove_outliers* returns a vector type. To ensure a vector always outputs, consider `vapply()` defining a length equal to input or `nrow(data_rm_val)`:

```
cleaned_data <- data.frame(vapply(data_rm_val, remove_outliers, numeric(nrow(data_rm_val))))
```

---

Above two options work on a dataset of random numbers (since OP does not provide example data):

```
data_rm_val <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),5))

#           X1         X2         X3         X4          X5
# 1  0.4303766  1.8152041  0.3355174 -0.4880282 -0.63612820
# 2  0.2876950 -0.7613642 -1.5046115  0.1821653  0.09397964
# 3 -2.3402548 -0.6771749 -2.0122667 -0.9442210 -1.30994853
# 4  1.4224979 -1.7940421 -0.5110736 -0.2837820 -0.24240172
# 5 -0.7484131 -0.8159326 -1.2690513 -1.0422656  1.23811458

cleaned_data <- data.frame(lapply(data_rm_val, remove_outliers))

#           X1         X2         X3         X4          X5
# 1  0.4303766         NA  0.3355174 -0.4880282 -0.63612820
# 2  0.2876950 -0.7613642 -1.5046115  0.1821653  0.09397964
# 3 -2.3402548 -0.6771749 -2.0122667 -0.9442210 -1.30994853
# 4  1.4224979         NA -0.5110736 -0.2837820 -0.24240172
# 5 -0.7484131 -0.8159326 -1.2690513 -1.0422656          NA

cleaned_data2 <- data.frame(vapply(data_rm_val, 
                                   remove_outliers, numeric(nrow(data_rm_val))))

#           X1         X2         X3         X4          X5
# 1  0.4303766         NA  0.3355174 -0.4880282 -0.63612820
# 2  0.2876950 -0.7613642 -1.5046115  0.1821653  0.09397964
# 3 -2.3402548 -0.6771749 -2.0122667 -0.9442210 -1.30994853
# 4  1.4224979         NA -0.5110736 -0.2837820 -0.24240172
# 5 -0.7484131 -0.8159326 -1.2690513 -1.0422656          NA
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Please accept the solution to confirm resolution.

Comment: unfortunately, my reputation is low around here. can only pray for you. Stay Blessed!

Comment: Not true. Original posters can accept any answer to their own question (see [check mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to side of solution). You even get points in doing so!